# Generic type 'FlatListProps<ItemT>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an article component to which I pass a `ListHeaderComponent` which is a props of `FlatListProps` like this:

```
<Test
    screen={screen}
/>
```

In `Test.tsx` I have set the following type:

```
type Props = {
    screen: ScreenType;
} & Omit<FlatListProps, 'data' | 'renderItem' | 'showsVerticalScrollIndicator'>;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Generic type 'FlatListProps<ItemT>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

But I am not quite sure what am I supposed to pass as an argument.

```
type Props = {
    screen: ScreenType;
} & Omit<FlatListProps<any>, 'data' | 'renderItem' | 'showsVerticalScrollIndicator'>;
```

This removes the error, however, I start getting the error the item explicitly has any type in the FlatList:

```
const Test: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ screen, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={screen.sections}
            renderItem={({ item: section, index }) => {
                return (
                    <Screen isFirst={index === 0}>
                        {screen.items.map((item, idx) => (
                            <Item key={idx} item={item} itemIndex={idx}/>
                        ))}
                    </Section>
                );
            }}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            {...rest}
        />
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [react-native code for FlatList](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b8425c8ee5b9dd685e80521555e6aff147e17874/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L31), it seems the `ItemT` in `FlatListProps<ItemT>` is the type of the element in the `data` array. So, in your case it would be the type of an `article.sections` element, which can be written as `ArticleType['sections'][number]`.